# Is (File.Encrypt) allowed with Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: c#, encryption, console-application

When I run the code below, my console app outputs:

"Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The Request is not supported."

```
static void Main()
{
    var xmlFile = "Encrypt.xml";

    File.Encrypt(xmlFile);
}
```

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium, coding with Visual Studio 2010, and coding in C#.
Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Which file system are you using? FAT32 or NTFS?

Comment: Sorry it took me long to reply.. I honestly don't know how to check for that..

Comment: Oh nvm, I'm tired sorry.. NTFS.

Comment: Yes, "Encrypt.xml" is in the debug folder; and I am running the program in debug mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [InformIT](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1416306&seqNum=2) article seems to indicate that it's only supported on the Professional and above editions.

In Summary:

> EFS is included in Windows XP Professional; Windows Vista Business, Enterprise, and Ultimate; and the Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate editions of Windows 7.

Comment: Well, that really is lame.. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: I would presume it would be because they believe encryption was an option targeted at businesses. Plus, I don't think people remember to back up their encryption certificates causing them to lose the data when they need to reinstall

Comment: You don't get bitlocker either, and until you get the Enterprise/Ultimate edition bitlocker can't be used for removable media. All the separate versions of windows make things really confusing for customers.

Comment: Dang.. Encrypting sounded interesting too, since I'm a new programmer..  Anyway, thanks for clarifying.